# ViewPager with Fragment with different layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am new to using `ViewPagers` and `Fragments` together.  My app has a `ListView` on startup, which bring the user to a details view based on a id that is passed.  The problem I'm running into is that the details view has a different layout then the list view.  The `ViewPager` is on the intial screen's layout, so when using the `ViewPager` the layout retains the inital layout, which is basically just a status bar at the bottom, which should go away when the user is on the details view.

This is what I have so far:

**Main.xml** (initial layout on startup, with a status bar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/status" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
        <!-- Footer -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/status
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Main.class**

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private static int NUMBER_OF_PAGES;  
    private ViewPager mViewPager;  
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter; 
    private static List<Fragment> fragments;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);  
        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);

        NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 5;

        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        fragments.add(new ListingFragment()); //initial screen that just a ListView

        fragments.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(1));
        fragments.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(2));
        fragments.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(3));
        fragments.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(4));
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {            

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            return fragments.get(index);
        }

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  

             return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;  
        }
   }
}
```

**Details.xml** (details view with no status bar)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**DetailsFragment.class**

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private int detailId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onActivityCreated(icicle);
    }

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int id) {

        DetailsFragment lf = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        lf.setArguments(bundle);
        return lf;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);

        detailId = getArguments().getInt("id");

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ViewPager is on the intial screen's layout, so when using the
>   ViewPager the layout retains the inital layout, which is basically
>   just a status bar at the bottom, which should go away when the user is
>   on the details view.

Then don't put it in the main layout file. If the status is tied to the first fragment then it belong in its view, especially if the `DetailsFragment` doesn't need to show that status `TextView`.

So remove the *status* `TextView` from *main.xml* and add it to the layout file used in the `ListingFragment`. If `ListingFragment` extends `ListFragment` then create a layout file which contains a `ListView` with the id(`android:id="@android:id/list"`) + the status `TextView` and inflate this layout file in the `onCreateView`.

Comment: That was it.  That should have been pretty obvious to me, though. :)  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18030296/1503130 , please give me some direction here @Luksprog